# How to formulate calculation using Function return values and procedures

Tags: vb.net

I have a series of functions and procedures that I've used to set specific values. How do I form a calculation based on these functions and procedures? Thanks.

Function DetermineBasePrice(ByVal baseRate As Decimal) As Decimal
        ' This function will determine the hairdresser base price

```
    If radJane.Checked Then
        baseRate = 30.0
    End If

    If radPat.Checked Then
        baseRate = 45.0
    End If

    If radRon.Checked Then
        baseRate = 40.0
    End If

    If radSue.Checked Then
        baseRate = 50.0
    End If

    If radLaura.Checked Then
        baseRate = 55.0
    End If

    Return baseRate
End Function

Function DetermineServicePrice(ByVal baseRate As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' This function will add each selected service price onto the current Base Price variable
    If chkCut.Checked Then
        baseRate += 30.0
    End If

    If chkColour.Checked Then
        baseRate += 40.0
    End If

    If chkExtensions.Checked Then
        baseRate += 50.0
    End If

    If chkHighlights.Checked Then
        baseRate += 200.0
    End If

    Return baseRate
End Function

Sub DetermineClientTypeDiscount(ByRef discount As Decimal)
    ' This procedure will determine the client type discount rate
    Dim totalPrice As Decimal

    If radAdult.Checked Then
        discount = 0

    ElseIf radChild.Checked Then
        discount = totalPrice * 0.1

    ElseIf radStudent.Checked Then
        discount = totalPrice * 0.05

    ElseIf radSenior.Checked Then
        discount = totalPrice * 0.15
    End If
End Sub

Sub DetermineVisitDiscount(ByRef additionalDiscount As Decimal, ByVal intClientVisits As Integer)
    ' This procedure will determine the visit discount rate

    Dim clientVisits As Integer

    If clientVisits >= 1 And clientVisits <= 3 Then
        additionalDiscount = 0

    ElseIf clientVisits >= 4 And clientVisits <= 8 Then
        additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.05

    ElseIf clientVisits >= 9 And clientVisits <= 13 Then
        additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.1

    ElseIf clientVisits >= 14 Then
        additionalDiscount = totalPrice * 0.15
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you filling fields on a form with the functions and procedures?

Comment: I'm adding items to a few listboxes and then calculating the price.

Comment: Please post more specific information about your request, including the code for at least one function/procedure and the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you doing the calculations in the same Sub? Do you have any code that can be looked at to get a reference on how you are doing the calculations currently?

Comment: I posted the code above.

Comment: So are you wanting to do the calculation on a button press or what? And I am not sure why you are passing `baseRate` to `Function DetermineBasePrice()` because the value is getting overwritten in that function and passed back. take out passing that variable `Function DetermineBasePrice() As Decimal`

Answer (score 0):

```
Function DetermineBasePrice() As Decimal

    If radJane.Checked Then
        return 30.0
    End If

    If radPat.Checked Then
        return 45.0
    End If

    If radRon.Checked Then
        return 40.0
    End If

    If radSue.Checked Then
        return 50.0
    End If

    If radLaura.Checked Then
        return 55.0
    End If

    Return 0
End Function

 Function DetermineServicePrice(ByVal baseRate As Decimal) As Decimal
     If chkCut.Checked Then
        baseRate += 30.0
     End If

    If chkColour.Checked Then
        baseRate += 40.0
    End If

    If chkExtensions.Checked Then
        baseRate += 50.0
    End If

    If chkHighlights.Checked Then
        baseRate += 200.0
    End If

    Return baseRate
End Function
Function DetermineClientTypeDiscount(ByVal baseRate As Decimal) as Decimal

    If radAdult.Checked Then
        return = 0

    ElseIf radChild.Checked Then
        return baseRate * 0.1

    ElseIf radStudent.Checked Then
        return baseRate * 0.05

    ElseIf radSenior.Checked Then
        return baseRate * 0.15
    End If
End Function

Function DetermineVisitDiscount(ByVal totalPrice As Decimal, ByVal intClientVisits As Integer) as Decimal

    If intclientVisits >= 1 And intclientVisits <= 3 Then
        return 0

    ElseIf intclientVisits >= 4 And intclientVisits <= 8 Then
        return totalPrice * 0.05

    ElseIf intclientVisits >= 9 And intclientVisits <= 13 Then
        return totalPrice * 0.1

    ElseIf intclientVisits >= 14 Then
        return totalPrice * 0.15
    End If
End Function
```

Ok, so after rewriting all your functions/subs we come out with these new ones. And here is how you would access them now

```
Dim totalPrice As Decimal = DetermineServicePrice(DetermineBasePrice())
Dim discount As Decimal = DetermineClientTypeDiscount(totalPrice)
Dim CustomerVisits As Integer = 1 'fill with where you are getting the visit count for the customer
Dim AdditionalDiscount As Decimal = DetermineVisitDiscount(totalPrice, CustomerVisits)
Dim FinalPrice as Decimal = totalPrice - discount - AdditionalDiscount
```

The only reason I broke it down into `discount` and `AdditionalDiscount` was just in case you were wanting to display these totals somewhere. Also I was not sure if you were wanting to apply the discounts in a certain order or apply them all at the end as I did. But here is a possible solution to your problem. Hope it helps. Next time please explain your question a little better and if you can't code it then try to write it in more detail exactly what you are trying to do.